# IQueryable<T1> extension method to convert to IQueryable<T2>

Tags: c#, iqueryable, generic-collections

Is it possible to add an extension method to an IQueryable that converts it to another type of IQueryable?

I looking for something like this;

```
IQueryable<foo> source;
IQueryable<bar> result = source.Convert<bar>();
```

I have this and obviously it is not working. LOL

```
public static IQueryable<T1> Convert<T2>(this IQueryable<T1> source) where T1 : class
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely it's already there in `Select` - you just need to provide the conversion. For example, to convert an `IQueryable<string>` to `IQueryable<int>` by taking the length:

```
IQueryable<string> source = ...;
IQueryable<int> lengths = source.Select(x => x.Length);
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for the reply. The reason why i would like to have this an an extension method is because I dont want to have to repeat the same select code. I was going to use this to convert my models into view models. Should I be looking at automapper?

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus: But `Select` is already an extension method. You haven't given us any information about how you expect to convert `T1` to `T2`... surely providing that information would make it equivalent to `Select`.

Comment: I was thinking that in the Convert extension method I could go through the items in the IQueryable and create a instance of T2 by passing the T1 to the constructor - but I just found out I can't just new up a T2 in this method like new T2(T1). I'll go with your answer and move on to the next challenge. Thanks so much for the answer and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the same type (`IQueryable<T1>`) that you have in your original queryable, so your extension method is taking an `IQueryable<foo>` and returning an `IQueryable<foo>` , where you want to return an `IQueryable<bar>`. Also, you define T2 as a generic type parameter, but not T1. You could change to this:

```
public static IQueryable<T2> Convert<T1, T2>(IQueryable<T1> source) where T1 : class
{
...
}
```

Then invoke like so:

```
IQueryable<Bar> result = source.Convert<Foo, Bar>();
```

But.. as Jon points out, this could be done in a Select. If the conversion between `foo` and `bar` is not so trivial, or you want to re-use it, you could define that mapping, rather than converting an IQueryable to IQueryable.

Comment: Thanks a lot SimonC. I decided to go with Jon's answer but I'll save your code as a snippet in case I need it for something else. Have a nice day! :)